# Jolt Transformation to flatten multi-value key input

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to flatten a JSON output using recursion but I'm not getting the desired output and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Input JSON:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "case": "case1",
      "doc": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "id": "id1"
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "id": "id2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "case": "case2",
      "doc": [
        {
          "name": "name3",
          "id": "id3"
        },
        {
          "name": "name4",
          "id": "id4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt Spec I'm currently using:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "foo": {
        "*": {
          "doc": {
            "*": {
              "name": "Doc[&1].name",
              "id": "Doc[&1].id",
              "@(2,case)": "Doc[&1].case"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output Received:

```json
{
  "Doc": [
    {
      "case": [
        "case1",
        "case2"
      ],
      "name": [
        "name1",
        "name3"
      ],
      "id": [
        "id1",
        "id3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "case": [
        "case1",
        "case2"
      ],
      "name": [
        "name2",
        "name4"
      ],
      "id": [
        "id2",
        "id4"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output Required:

```
{
  "Doc": [
    {
      "case": "case1",
      "name": "name1",
      "id": "id1"
    },
    {
      "case": "case2",
      "name": "name2",
      "id": "id2"
    },
    {
      "case": "case3",
      "name": "name3",
      "id": "id3"
    },
    {
      "case": "case4",
      "name": "name4",
      "id": "id4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I rummaged through a bunch of docs but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to add one more node to distinguish the sub-objects. Btw, no need to to replicate each attribute name individually, rather use symbols **`*`** and **`&`** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "foo": {
        "*": {
          "doc": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,case)": "[&3].&1.case",
              "*": "[&3].&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "Doc"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yup that works like a charm. If you don't mind, can you explain the use cases of & and @?

Comment: Hi @SenthamizhSelvan , nice to help. `&` stands for substitution where no need to repeat the current key by using that. A shorthand for `&0`. Here the integer represents the level to go the tree up. For example, you can obtain the key `doc` by using `&2` for the innermost level within the first transformation. `@` represents the current value of the current attribute(not key but value, eg. right hand side), and the same logic with the ampersand works whenever using indexes along with it such as `@1`, `@2` ..etc.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you @BarbarosOzhan